# Issue with CWM recovery mode

Tags: rooting, 5.0-lollipop, recovery-mode, 5.1-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-j3

I have flashed CWM onto my phone by using Odin as I'm trying to root, but when I boot into recovery mode, it just takes me to the stock recovery mode, and not the CWM version, so I can't install the ZIP. How do I get around this, or boot directly into CWM recovery mode?

I am running a Samsung Galaxy J3 2016 Edition running Android 5.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootloader is most likely still locked, detects a recovery tamper then reflashes the stock recovery. 
Try flashing [CF-Auto-Root](https://autoroot.chainfire.eu/) for your device and then flash [TWRP](https://twrp.me/Devices/) and boot into it right as the device is rebooting after Odin's flash. Flash whatever ROM you're looking to install while you're in recovery and it should keep the recovery you have just flashed.

Comment: Thank you, I have now advanced further. I flash it through Odin, but first turn off auto reboot, then take out the battery, and go into recovery mode. But when I go into recovery mode, it just says "recovery is not seandroid enforcing". How do I get around this?

Comment: That's fine if it says that. 
It just means essentially it is not a stock recovery, some recoveries do trick it into think thinking it is seandroid enforcing.
If you get that message and it won't boot into recovery, you've flashed the wrong file. Just repeat said steps and make sure you flash the correct file for your carrier variant.